# nginx to always serve the root index.html in every path

Tags: nginx

I have currently the code below. I am wondering if it's possible to still service this root even though I go to other pages like http://localhost/dog. The problem with my command below is it will return 404

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name         localhost;

    location / {
        root /usr/src/app/angularjs/dist;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible. Add the `try_files` directive to your `location` block, this will tell nginx to load all requests that cannot be matched to a filesystem path with your `index.html`:

`try_files $uri /index.html;`